# Is there any way to see how many actors an ActorSystem has, and what their names are?

Tags: c#, akka.net

I am thinking about building a system that pre-fetches queries for the user using information in a currently returned query (the user queries the DB for a userId, that returns a list of phone calls the user has been on.  I want to pre-fetch the queries for the phone calls (things like date, duration, and location of the recorded phone call).  The user may never query those things, but they generally do.

Currently, each query is taking ~10 seconds (there's some optimization that needs to happen in the code, but the big bottleneck is the DB and that's out of my hands).

So, I want to do the prefetching with actors.  I'll eventually figure out a way for the actors to kill themselves if they go unused for x time, but first I'd like a way to see what actors I have running.

Is there any way to do that in Akka.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you could model this is by having an parent actor that handles a certain set of prefetchingActor(s). Werther you have one Actor that manages all your prefetches, or multiple ones where each one manages a specialized set of prefetchers is up to you.

But the point is that you will end up with a well-defined top level actor(s) which you can send a message to ask how many active prefetchers it has.

Update:

You can use ActorSelection and wildcards to send a message to multiple actors.

Regarding handling timeouts. I'd use a passivate pattern. A child actor can use the `ReceiveTimeout` method to monitor its own activity, and send a passivate message to its parent once it detects its been idle for x amount of time.
Once the parent receives the passivate message it would stop routing messages to the child, buffering them instead. And stop the actor. Once actor termination is confirmed, it would check if there are any new messages for that actor, if so recreate the actor and flush messages from its buffer to it.

Comment: But there's no real way to get them by name?  I guess the top level actor could have a state that manages that, as well as the last time the child actor was accessed.  Then the parent actor would handle the timeouts and such.

Comment: updated the answer. Since it was to much for a comment.